# Virtualbox & Vagrant keep consuming memory constantly

Tags: memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, vagrant, virtualbox

I am running a Windows2012R2 vagrant box, using VirtualBox as a provider, on a host system: 14.04.1-Ubuntu/3.16.0-40-generic with 32GB of physical memory. For some reason, VirtualBox and/or Vagrant are completely eating up all of my machine's memory and I want to understand why and fix the problem.

- When I first start the vagrant box, I have 92% free memory, with 0% cached
- By the time it has booted and has its hostname set, its more like 10% free, with 32% cached (if I shut the VM down and snapshot it after it first boots, the memory will only go down to about 35% free).
- After it's booted, it will continue to consume/cache more and more memory until there is 0% free

My vagrants are configured as such:

```
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "4096"]
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--vram", "64"]
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--autostart-enabled", "off"]
vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpuexecutioncap", "40"]
```

Seems to me that there should be plenty of unused RAM on my box, still. In fact, I should easily be able to run three of these at the same time without all the host memory getting consumed, right?

*(Incidentally, if I shut all the VMs down, I don't get much memory back, whereas, if I "vagrant destroy" them all, all of my host machine's memory will be instantly restored. I don't know if that helps identify the problem, but I figure, it can't hurt.)*

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help on this one!

Comment: Host: Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager 4.3.30 / Guest: Oracle VM Virtualbox Guest Additions 4.3.12r93733